# NSUserDefault not loading in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a main view with a button that when pressed it adds the url from the web view(like a bookmark) to a table view. The only problem is that its not loading. ive been at it for hours now but cant figure it out. I think i am loading the data in the table view wrong but not quiet sure.

This is the MainViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)bookmark:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = 
        [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:[[[[self webView] request] URL]
            absoluteString] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
            destructiveButtonTitle:nil  otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];
     [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSMutableArray *bookmarks = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
            arrayForKey:@"Bookmarks"] mutableCopy];

        if (!bookmarks) {
            bookmarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [bookmarks addObject:[[[[self webView]request] URL] absoluteString]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks
            forKey:@"Bookmarks"];
    }
}
```

This is BookmarksViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@", bookmarks);

    bookmarks = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                  arrayForKey:@"Bookmarks"] mutableCopy];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"Bookmarks"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is there any place where you synchronize NSUserDefaults?

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: I have actually synchronized it now but that didn't solve the problem. @Jonathan

Comment: You don't need to call `synchronize`. It is done automatically.

Comment: Do you have a view controller? Why are you using main.m like this?

Comment: yes *MainViewController.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your app is first run there is nothing set for the `Bookmarks` key in `NSUserDefaults`. So the line:

```
bookmarks = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
              arrayForKey:@"Bookmarks"] mutableCopy];
```

in `viewDidLoad` leaves `bookmarks` set to `nil`.

In your action sheet handler you actually deal with this properly.

And one other big problem is the call to:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"Bookmarks"];
```

in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath...` method. Why do you update `NSUserDefaults` every time a cell is needed? Don't do this.

Comment: ok so i reloaded my table view, i got rid of [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"Bookmarks"];
  but what should i do for the method in viewDidLoad.

Comment: The same thing you do in your action sheet handler. Check for `nil` and handle it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The command `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` does NOT always return a cell. It only returns a cell if there is a cell in the reusable-cell queue.

So your method should be:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"Bookmarks"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your statement is not necessarily true. There are cases where `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` never returns `nil`. But regardless, if that were the problem then there would be a runtime error for returning `nil` from the `cellForRow...` method. None of this has anything to do with why the bookmarks don't appear.